# How would I extract a title from a script using bs4

Tags: database, beautifulsoup, request

I am trying to extract the title from HTML located in a `</script>` where I want to assign a variable only to the `Timer 5 mins 3 sec`.

Heres the HTML

```
</script>
<title>Timer 5 mins 3 sec - 24/9/2020</title>
```

Heres what I've done so far

```py
with requests.Session() as s:
  r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
  itemitle = soup.find(True,{"script":"title"})
  print(itemitle)
```

But this does not seem to find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`title` is the tag and you can use the [`type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors) (tag) selector. It is not inside the `script` tag (as shown), e.g.

`soup.select_one('title')`.

With bs4 4.7.1+ you can use `:contains` to specify has "`Timer`" substring, or longer substring.

e.g.

```
soup.select_one('title:contains("Timer")')
```

This assumes the content is not dynamically generated. In that case, you will need to determine if comes from an additional xhr found in the network tab, or the javascript generating it.